Webpack config to single file
I'm having trouble building a Preact widget project,
Before that, I used microbundle to build index.js and index.css files
Then I want to use webpack to build one more time to combine these 2 files into 1 js file to embed into other websites that need to use it.
[enter image description here][1]


// webpack.config.js
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./dist/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: [
              ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: "defaults" }],
              ["@babel/preset-react", { runtime: "automatic" }],
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {},
  plugins:[
    new Dotenv()
  ]
};



[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Q6HxL.png

What do you mean "...to combine these 2 files into 1 js file"? Do you intend to embed the CSS into the JS file? Microbundle supports this out-of-the-box, you don't need a secondary Webpack build for it.

yes my aim is to bundle my Preact widget into 1 single JS file, how does microbundle support it can you suggest me?
This is the section in package.json that defines the build command using my microbundle
"build:widget": "microbundle build  --format cjs --sourcemap=false",

Oh, I see option 'css --inline', Did you mean that option?

Yep, css --inline is what you want. That inlines the CSS into a string in your JS file, allowing you to (say) inject it into a <style> tag. Now, obligatory warning: use this only if you absolutely have to. It is much, much better to keep these as separate files for performance reasons. CSS inlined into JS is very wasteful.

`import { clsx, type ClassValue } from "clsx";
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";
export function cn(...inputs: ClassValue[]) {
return twMerge(clsx(inputs));
}`
I use clsx in the project, after building to index.js, I embed the index.js file into a script tag, I get a console.error(Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined), Do you know that case

You've set --format cjs, but CJS is only valid in Node (require() is specific to CJS) -- any of the other formats (ESM, Modern, UMD) will work fine in a browser environment though. If it's easier, feel free to open an issue on the Microbundle repo and I can walk you through it a bit better, as this is a tad off-topic for StackOverflow.
